# 2d Array - Each Row being Overwritten by Next

Tags: c, arrays, 2d, overwrite

I'm reading in from a file. Whenever I read in the word 'transition' I'm trying to add the next 5 elements that appear to a 2d array. I have a bunch of printf's which I have commented out that show that I am adding the proper element. However, once I finish reading in from file, I loop through to check my 2d array values and they have all been overwritten by the last row's values.

Here is my code

```
State* allStates[1002];
State* currentState;
char* input = argv[1];
char* inputStr = argv[2];
int maxTrans = atoi(argv[3]);
int transCount = -1;
FILE* inputFile;
char* transition[maxTrans][5];  

inputFile = fopen(input, "r");
if (inputFile == 0)
{
    perror("Can't open file\n");
    exit(-1);   
}
else
{
    char next[1000];
    //int counter = 0;
    while (fgets(next, 1000, inputFile) != NULL)
    {
        char *nextWord;
        nextWord = strtok_r(next, "\t");

        if (strcmp(nextWord, "state") == 0)
        {

            //counter++;
            nextWord = strtok_r(NULL, "\t");
            //puts(nextWord);
            int q = atoi(nextWord);
            nextWord = strtok_r(NULL, "\n");
            //puts(nextWord);
            if (strcmp(nextWord, "accept") == 0)
            {
                State* newState = makeState(q, 1, 0, 0);    
                allStates[q] = newState;
            }
            else if (strcmp(nextWord, "reject") == 0)
            {
                State* newState = makeState(q, 0, 1, 0);    
                allStates[q] = newState;
            }
            else if (strcmp(nextWord, "start") == 0)
            {
                State* newState = makeState(q, 0, 0, 1);    
                allStates[q] = newState;
                currentState = newState;
            } 
            else    
            {
                State* newState = makeState(q, 0, 0, 0);    
                allStates[q] = newState;
            }           
        }
        if (strcmp(nextWord, "transition") == 0)
        {
            //printf("\n");
            //setup 2d array of transitions
            transCount++;
            nextWord = strtok_r(NULL, "\t");
            //puts(nextWord);
            transition[transCount][0] = nextWord;
            //printf("%c", *transition[transCount][0]);
            nextWord = strtok_r(NULL, "\t");
            //puts(nextWord);
            transition[transCount][1] = nextWord;
            //printf("%c", *transition[transCount][1]);
            nextWord = strtok_r(NULL, "\t");
            //puts(nextWord);
            transition[transCount][2] = nextWord;
            //printf("%c", *transition[transCount][2]);
            nextWord = strtok_r(NULL, "\t");
            //puts(nextWord);
            transition[transCount][3] = nextWord;
            //printf("%c", *transition[transCount][3]);
            nextWord = strtok_r(NULL, "\n");
            //puts(nextWord);
            transition[transCount][4] = nextWord;   
            //printf("%c", *transition[transCount][4]); 

        }
    }

}   
fclose(inputFile);

int u = 0;
int y = 0;
char m = 'm';
for (u; u < 12; u++)
{
    printf("\n");
    for (y = 0; y < 5; y++)
    {
        //transition[u][y] = &m;

        printf("%c", *transition[u][y]);


    }
}
```

If the file I'm reading in looks like this,

transition  0   x   0   x   R

transition  0   1   4   1   L

transition  0   0   1   x   R

I expect the array to look like this

0x0xR

0141L

001xR

Instead the values of the array will be

001xR

001xR

001xR

I know that the overwriting happens at each row. ie: when I'm writing to row 2 the values become:

0141L

0141L

I'm really lost as to how to fix it though.

Comment: `strtok()` doesn't make copies of the tokens for you, it just gives you a pointer to them in the original string (in which it also replaces the separators).  If you're reusing the same buffer for each row, your pointers from all rows will point into that same buffer, and show whatever is there now.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. As given, there is not even the definition of the array.

Comment: So would it be possible to use strcpy and save strtok() to a different variable then set my 2d array equal to that variable?

Comment: You just need to allocate storage for a string and copy the token to it, assigning the pointer to the allocated storage instead of assigning the pointer returned by `strtok()` directly.  You could use `malloc()` + `strcpy()`, or if you have it `strdup()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my incorrect usage of strtok(). I took Dmitri's advice and used strdup() which allocates memory for the new string and I'm getting the proper results.

```
nextWord = strtok(NULL, "\t");
temp = strdup(nextWord);
transition[transCount][0] = temp;
```